# Calculo de desviación estandar en panda

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Mi problema a resolver trata de un DataFrame de la lista de descargas de modelos, como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el cual tengo que crear un DataFrame resultado que obtenga por cada modelo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para ello he hecho este código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:dict)->pd.DataFrame:
    # Paso 1: cargar los datos
    df = pd.DataFrame(descargas)
    
    # TRUE y FALSE son strings por lo que hay que convertirlos a booleanos
    # Convertir TRUE a True y FALSE a False
    df['COMENTARIO'] = df['COMENTARIO'].map({'TRUE': True, 'FALSE': False})
    #cambiamos los valores de la columna a 0 ó 1
    df["COMENTARIO"] = df["COMENTARIO"].apply(lambda x: int(x)) #1 if str(x)=="True" else 0
    df_pagados = df[df["PAGO"] > 0]
    grupo = df_pagados.groupby("modelo")

    #obtenemos los datos
    count_comentarios = grupo["COMENTARIO"].sum().to_list() #contabilizacion de comentariso True
    cantidad = grupo["COMENTARIO"].count().to_list() #cantidad
    prom = grupo[["PAGO","ESTRELLAS"]].mean() #promedio de Pago y estrellas, no se convierte a lista
    min,max =  grupo["PAGO"].min().to_list(), grupo["PAGO"].max().to_list() #minimos y maximos
    #obtenemos los indices y los metemos en una lista
    indexs = [ind for ind in prom.index]
    #creamos el diccionario donde la llave es el nombre de la columna y el valor es la lista
    new_data = {"CANTIDAD":cantidad,"COMENTARIOS":count_comentarios,"MINIMO":min,"MAXIMO":max}
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data,index=indexs) #creamos el nuevo DF
    new_df["PAGO"] = prom["PAGO"] #agregamos la columna pago a partir del anterior df
    new_df["ESTRELLAS"] = prom["ESTRELLAS"] #agregamos la columna estrellas a partir del anterior df
    return new_df
```

Solo faltaría por calcular la desviación estándar que no se como hacerlo porque hay una condición:
Como la desviación estándar no se puede calcular cuando haya
sólo un dato, en lugar de NaN debe aparecer 0.0 en el resultado.

Además de ello al probarlo tal y como esta escrito el código me aparecen estos problemas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No es la opción más elegante (se que existe)... se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd


def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:dict)->pd.DataFrame:
  '''Descripción detallada de la función'''

  if isinstance(descargas, dict):
    # Creamos un dataFrame con los datos de «diccionario»
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=descargas, orient='columns')

    # Para los (pagos==0) cambiamos el cero (0) por NaN
    df['Modelo']= df['Modelo'].where(df['Pago']>0)
    # Eliminamos los valores NaN
    df = df.drop('Usuario', axis=1).dropna()

    ### Agrupamos por 'Modelo' y calculamos: (minimos, maximos, promedios,
    # desviaciones std) de las columnas ('Pago' 'Estrellas' 'Comentario')
    pago = df[['Modelo', 'Pago']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['count','mean','max', 'min']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    # Eliminamos el nivel superior creado en las columnas
    pago.columns = pago.columns.droplevel()
    # Cambiamos el nombre de las columnas
    pago.columns = ['CANTIDAD', 'PROMEDIO', 'MAXIMO', 'MINIMO']

    
    estrellas = df[['Modelo', 'Estrellas']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['max','std']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    estrellas.columns = estrellas.columns.droplevel()
    estrellas.columns = ['ESTRELLAS', 'DEV.ESTRELLAS']

    comentarios = df[['Modelo', 'Comentario']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['sum']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    comentarios.columns = comentarios.columns.droplevel()
    comentarios.columns = ['COMENTARIOS']
    
    # Concatenomos lo dataframes «pago», «estrellas» y «comentarios» 
    df = pd.concat([pago, estrellas, comentarios], axis=1)

     
    return df

  raise TypeError( "‼\n\n  Tipo de parametro incorrecto...\n"\
                      f"\n\t«descargas» es:        {str(type(descargas))} ✘"\
                       "\n\t«descargas» debe ser:  <class 'dict'> ✔\n")





def main():
  '''Funcion principal'''
  diccionario = { 'Modelo': ['Bus urbano #27','Silla tipo bar','Piano','Fuente con flores','Bus urbano #27','Puesto de Yogurt','Playground','Bus urbano #27'],
                 'Usuario': ['Ted Mosby','Art Vandelay','Art Vandelay','Michael','Mark Brendanawicz','Michael','LeCorbusier_2020',''],
                 'Pago': [24.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0],
                 'Estrellas': [5, 3.5,3.5,5,4,5,4.5,1],
                 'Comentario': [True]+[False]*2+[True]*5 }
  
  calcular_estadisticas(diccionario)





if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

La función retornaría:

```
                CANTIDAD  PROMEDIO  MAXIMO  MINIMO  ESTRELLAS  DEV.ESTRELLAS  COMENTARIOS
Modelo                                                                                   
Bus urbano #27         2    18.495   24.99   12.00        5.0       0.707107            2
Piano                  1     4.990    4.99    4.99        3.5       0.000000            0
Playground             1    14.000   14.00   14.00        4.5       0.000000            1
Silla tipo bar         1     4.990    4.99    4.99        3.5       0.000000            0
```

Otra opción (la cual me parece mas refinada) seria...

```
import pandas as pd


diccionario = { 'Modelo': ['Bus urbano #27','Silla tipo bar','Piano','Fuente con flores','Bus urbano #27','Puesto de Yogurt','Playground','Bus urbano #27'],
                 'Usuario': ['Ted Mosby','Art Vandelay','Art Vandelay','Michael','Mark Brendanawicz','Michael','LeCorbusier_2020',''],
                 'Pago': [24.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0],
                 'Estrellas': [5, 3.5,3.5,5,4,5,4.5,1],
                 'Comentario': [True]+[False]*2+[True]*5 }


# Creamos un dataFrame con los datos de «diccionario»
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=diccionario, orient='columns')

# Para los (pagos==0) cambiamos el cero (0) por NaN
df['Modelo']= df['Modelo'].where(df['Pago']>0)
# Eliminamos los valores NaN
df = df.drop('Usuario', axis=1).dropna()


### Agrupamos por 'Modelo' y calculamos: (minimos, maximos, promedios,
# desviaciones std) de las columnas ('Pago' 'Estrellas' 'Comentario')
df = df.groupby('Modelo').agg(['count','min', 'max','mean','std']).fillna(0).sort_index()
```

Después eliminas las columnas innecesarias con:

```
df.drop(('Pago', 'std'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(('Pago', 'sum'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```